# SneakyInput joystick touch event ends when CCButton is pressed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I've added a joystick to my iOS game using the latest SneakyInput joystick code for cocos2d v3. It works well, but when a `CCButton` I have is pressed, the joystick touch event ends.

Based on my research, I've already set multitouch:

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector].view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

I've even tried setting `multipleTouchEnabled` for every button/joystick node, but still nothing works. Every time I touch the button, the joystick `touchEnded` method is called.

Here's the joystick code:

```
leftJoy = [[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init];
leftJoy.position = ccp(96,96);
leftJoy.backgroundSprite = [ColoredCircleSprite circleWithColor:[CCColor colorWithCcColor4b: ccc4(21, 21, 21, 127)] radius:64];
leftJoy.thumbSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"joystick.png"];
leftJoy.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc] initWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,128,128)];
leftJoy.joystick.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; // just testing
leftJoy.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; // just testing
[self addChild:leftJoy];
```

And my button code:

```
fire = [CCButton
                  buttonWithTitle:nil
                  spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"fire-enabled.png"]
                  highlightedSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"fire-active.png"]
                  disabledSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"fire.png"]];
fire.position = ccp(x,y);
fire.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; // testing
[fire setTarget:[World sharedWorld].player selector:@selector(fire:)];
[self addChild:fire];
```

The joystick works fine. Until the fire button is pressed.

I *could* redesign my buttons to use the sneakyinput button, but they work fine as-is except for this one issue.

Comment: Can you provide the whole sneakyjoy class ? Hard to tell. Maybe the problem is in there.

Comment: Try this, in your main scene that loads the interface: [CCDirector sharedDirector].view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 1):

Use `CCSprite` instead of `CCButton`.

Handle every `CCSprite` touch event in TouchDelegate method.

Inherite class where you are using  SneakyInput joystick by `CCLayer` with Touch Enable.

Link : https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput